# Uncaught Reference - myFunction() is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read probably 50 topics here about this error, but looks like I didn't manage to find a way to fix my case.

Here is the code I'm using :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var NAME,CATEGORY,NEED,PIMP;
    function myFunction(){
     NAME = document.getElementById("NAME").value; 
     CATEGORY = document.getElementById("CATEGORY").value;
     NEED = document.getElementById("NEED").value;
     PIMP = document.getElementById("PIMP").value;
     alert();
    }       
        (function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json",
            data: {name:NAME, category:CATEGORY, need:NEED, pimp:PIMP},
            url: "send.php",
            success: function(result) {
            alert('Good job');
            }
        });
        }
    ); 
</script>
```

```html
<div>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">BOOM!</a>
</div>
```

It is suppose to collect var from multiple form when I click on the button and to send me the content by mail... But I still have this error in the console "myFunction is undefined".

Comment: Is the POST supposed to be part of myFunction()? If yes, you have to move the } in front of `jQuery(function($) {` all the way to the end.

Comment: Have you tried using jquery .click function rather than the onClick html

Comment: Surely you can see the *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"* error

Comment: Ok I moved the bracket to the end, and nothing changed, I still have the same error. I'll check the other answers too. I probably made a lot of mistakes..

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery-part of your script contains a syntax-error, therefore the entire script-block(including `myFunction`) will be discarded.

Fix the Syntax-error.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('call of myFunction')
  var NAME = document.getElementById("NAME").value;
  var CATEGORY = document.getElementById("CATEGORY").value;
  var NEED = document.getElementById("NEED").value;
  var PIMP = document.getElementById("PIMP").value;
}

/**
jQuery(function($) {
  type: "POST",//<--syntax-error
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    name: NAME,
    category: CATEGORY,
    need: NEED,
    pimp: PIMP
  },
  url: "send.php",
  success: function(result) {
    alert('Good job');
  }
});
**/
```

```html
<div>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">BOOM!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume OP meant to use `$.ajax` in there but missed it somehow

Comment: I guess too, but JS didn't care about what somebody means, it's a syntax-error

Comment: While this answer is correct, it will probally be unclear to the user why it's a syntax error. It's because the user is simply using a `document.ready` event, and hence normal code would be inside. I would mention what @Phil noted. Basically add a *"This is a syntax error **because ...**"*

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this part (and edited the code I have in my post) but I still have the same error: "myFunction is undefined".

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely an issue related to *where* you are putting your code. I'm guessing at the end of your html, after the html was rendered.

In any case, if you happen to fix that your code still won't work because the variables inside your function are local and won't be accessible inside your ajax call.

Since you are using jQuery I'd do this:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
  var NAME = document.getElementById("NAME").value; 
  var CATEGORY = document.getElementById("CATEGORY").value;
  var NEED = document.getElementById("NEED").value;
  var PIMP = document.getElementById("PIMP").value;

  $.post(your url, { name: name...}, function() { alert('Good job'); });
}
```

Comment: It's not related to the location of the `<script>` block. Otherwise, good advice

Comment: If your using jquery anyway why not use the $('#id').val() rather than the document calls

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to put object syntax as the body of a function, not inside of an object.  You can either do

```
var a = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
}
```

Another option is just pass it directly as a parameter, as I am doing below.

I believe the syntax you are looking for is something like below

```
var NAME,CATEGORY,NEED,PIMP;
    function myFunction(){
     NAME = document.getElementById("NAME").value; 
     CATEGORY = document.getElementById("CATEGORY").value;
     NEED = document.getElementById("NEED").value;
     PIMP = document.getElementById("PIMP").value;
        alert();
    }       
        $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json",
            data: {name:NAME, category:CATEGORY, need:NEED, pimp:PIMP},
            url: "send.php",
            success: function(result) {
            alert('Good job');
            }
        });
        }
    );
```

Note I also made your variables NAME, CATEGORY, NEED, and PIMP global because you were declaring them within the scope of myFunction() and trying to access them outside that scope

Comment: I tried your code instead of mine. I have the first alert when I click on the button now.

And I have a syntax error with the line dataType: "json" (looks like I had it before too)

Comment: here is a fiddle where I am not receiving the error you mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/e6e93zed/1/

Comment: Yes, exactly, I wanted to edit to correct my comment. I actually don't have this error anymore! But still, I can't see where it doesn't work now.

Comment: is myFunction supposed to make the ajax call? because right now you have the ajax call outside of the function body, so it is calling on page load. Here is the format to have it fire within myFunction.  http://jsfiddle.net/e6e93zed/2/   I also gave you error response messages to play with

Comment: thank you for the code. myFunction is supposed to get the var from the different form and then to do the call. I'm not really at ease with js as you can see.

I tried to use the code you sent and it says that it can't read the ajax property or it's undefined.

Comment: do you have a jquery reference on your page? $.ajax is part of the jquery library.

Comment: I added '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">' with the same result (myFunction is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Where you put myFunction? If you're putting this function inside DOMready function, then remove it out and place inside `script` immedietly :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var NAME = document.getElementById("NAME").value;
  var CATEGORY = document.getElementById("CATEGORY").value;
  var NEED = document.getElementById("NEED").value;
  var PIMP = document.getElementById("PIMP").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be about when your script loads compared to when your element loads. so it might be undefined because the script hasn't been loaded but the document has you could fix this and make your code simpler using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myButton').click(function() {
  var NAME = $(".NAME").val();
  var CATEGORY = $(".CATEGORY").val();
  var NEED = $(".NEED").val();
  var PIMP = $(".PIMP").val();
   jQuery.post('send.php',{'name': NAME,'category': CATEGORY, 'need': NEED,'pimp': PIMP},function(result) {alert('Good job');},"json");
});
});
```

That should work regardless of when things load. the `$(document).ready();` is making sure the document is loaded before the function is called at which point it should be able to find your button based on the css selector. there was also a problem with your post request but i believe i fixed that as well. the last problem was that originally your post request was not inside of your function so it was run separately rather then right after your variables are declared

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your function isn't being defined in the global scope, try defining it as a property of window:

```
window.myFunction = function(){ ... }
```

Comment: It's directly after a `<script>` tag, so it will be in global scope.